# ASP.NET Bootstrap quebra de formularios em dispositivos moveis

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Desenvolvi um site com ASP.NET e bootstrap o layout esta ok para aplicativos com tela ate o tamanho do ipad. Porem no ipad mini gostaria que ocorre-se uma quebra de linha onde o LstLojas fique acima do restante do formulário atualmente ambos ficam na mesma linha e por isso se sobre poem.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <asp:ListBox ID="LstLojas" runat="server" height="156px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="from-group">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocal" runat="server" placeholder="Local" class="col-xs-10"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocalID" runat="server" placeholder="ID" class="col-xs-2 text-muted"></asp:TextBox>


      <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndereco" runat="server" placeholder="Endereço" class="col-xs-8"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtComplemento" runat="server" placeholder="Complemento" class="col-xs-4"></asp:TextBox>


      <asp:TextBox ID="txtBairro" runat="server" placeholder="Bairro" class="col-xs-4"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCidade" runat="server" placeholder="Cidade" class="col-xs-4"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtUf" runat="server" placeholder="Uf" class="col-xs-2"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCep" runat="server" placeholder="CEP" class="col-xs-2"></asp:TextBox>


      <asp:TextBox ID="txtContato1" runat="server" placeholder="Contato 1" class="col-xs-8"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDDD1" runat="server" placeholder="DDD" class="col-xs-2"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtTelefone1" runat="server" placeholder="Telefone" class="col-xs-2"></asp:TextBox>


      <asp:TextBox ID="txtContato2" runat="server" placeholder="Contato 2" class="col-xs-8"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDDD2" runat="server" placeholder="DDD" class="col-xs-2"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtTelefone2" runat="server" placeholder="Telefone" class="col-xs-2"></asp:TextBox>


      <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail1" runat="server" placeholder="Email 1" class="col-xs-6"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail2" runat="server" placeholder="Email 2" class="col-xs-6"></asp:TextBox>


      <asp:Label ID="lblAtualizacao" runat="server" Text="Ultima altualização: "></asp:Label>
      <br />
      <asp:Label ID="lblStatusSuccess" runat="server" Text="" class="text-success"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lblStatusError" runat="server" Text="" class="text-danger"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" cssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Salvar" />
    <asp:Button id="Button2" runat="server" cssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Excluir" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Recomendo dar uma lida - http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%C3%ADtulo

Comment: Estranho não quebrar linha, pois estão em rows diferentes. Você está usando uma div externa com a class container?